# twillo does not work with civicrm

Tags: civisms

From Civicrm I tried to send sms but it didn't work, I tried meshes> new sms then I selected as Twilio supplier and select the group where my constact is located but none of them are 'is find.
Have a good day

Comment: not sure i can help but i can confirm we have Twilio working with civicrm

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pete